# Pass variable update from static js File nextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to do a conditional render in my component, but I can't even show the value of a variable.

I have in one file, all my funtions that I export in my index.js

```
import FunctionServices from "../services/functionServices"

export default function Connect() {

 //const [accountId, setAccountId] = useState()

//let accountId = FunctionServices.accountId

//useEffect(() => {
//    setAccountId(FunctionServices.accountId)
//})

return (
<span>{FunctionServices.accountID}<span/>
<button onClick = {()=> FunctionServices.initconnect}> </button>
)

}
```

And in functionServices where I have all my functions I have :

```
let accountId;

async function initconnect() {

    //Account Id

    connect.pairingEvent.once(
        pairingData => {
            pairingData.accountIds.forEach(id => {
                accountId = id;
                console.log(`The account id is ${accountId}`)
            })
        }
    )
}
export default {accountId, initconnect}
```

I my functionServices file, I can show the accountId, and it console it, but how can I make it show in my index.js. Also when it changes.

I tried with the context api, but got stuck, because I didn't know how to wrap the functions in the provider, since it's not a component (functionServices)

Thanks for your help and explanations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to put export in front of each functions, instead of putting them all in the export default {...}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

write your index.js as

```js
import FunctionServices from "../services/functionServices"

export default function Connect() {
  const [accountId, setAccountId] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
      FunctionServices.initconnect(setAccountId)
  }, [])

  return (
    <span>{accountId}<span/>
  )

}
```

And initConnect function as

```js
async function initconnect(callback) {

    //Account Id

    connect.pairingEvent.once(
        pairingData => {
            pairingData.accountIds.forEach(id => {
                accountId = id;
                callback(id);
                console.log(`The account id is ${accountId}`)
            })
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I have the error call back is not a function

Comment: I tried doing it outside the function like so 
`const log = (callback) => {
    console.log(accountId)
    callback(accountId);
}` 
it works when calling this function after initconnect. But I need it to load in the initconnect, and when I do so it says it's not a function

Comment: @IlyesMakria if possible can you give me the link for the source code